# Type Mismatch when Selecting Column with a formula VBA(Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, types, mismatch

The following is a code section that I have in my VBA program:

```
Columns("currentColumn:(currentColumn+1)").Select
```

For some reason I have a type mismatch when I run this. currentColumn is an Integer. This is my first time using VBA so I'm sure I'm missing something. I was wondering if someone could point me towards the right track.

Thanks

Comment: Oh I See. Is there something similar to columns that allows me to pass in numbers?

Comment: `Range(Columns(currentColumn),Columns(currentColumn+1)).Select`

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Scott's suggestion:

The problem is not only that `Columns` doesn't accept inputs like `"2:3"` (`Rows` would work with that but for `Columns` you'd need `"B:C"`). The problem is also that `"currentColumn:(currentColumn+1)"` is a string consisting of exactly these characters. The variable `currentColumn"` isn't replaced and the addition `+1` isn't executed either. If you want to build a string with the number currentColumn and not the string `"currentColumn` you need to use `&`:

```
currentColumn & ":" & currentColumn + 1 'if currentColumn = 2 then this is the same as "2:3"
```

---

note that you usually don't need to `Select` objects. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) are some examples on how to avoid it.